# How to generate a complex gaussian white noise signal in python(or numpy/scipy)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am doing some works about DSP(digital signal process), and there need to generate a discrete complex white gaussian noise signal. I know I can use `numpy.random.normal(0, 1, n)` to generate the discrete sequence, but it is in real number field. It is easy to simulate with Matlab, but I wander how to replace matlab code with python?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it.  This generates an array of standard normal variates of shape (n, 2), and then uses the `.view()` method to view the array as an array of complex values with shape (n,).

```
In [26]: n = 10                                                                                                     

In [27]: z = np.random.randn(n, 2).view(np.complex128)                                                              

In [28]: z                                                                                                          
Out[28]: 
array([[ 0.90179497-0.14081956j],
       [-2.17633115+0.88782764j],
       [ 0.94807348+0.27575325j],
       [-1.25452512+0.64883484j],
       [-0.58886548+0.15419947j],
       [ 0.58296574+1.45711421j],
       [ 0.803825  +0.6197812j ],
       [ 0.09225137+0.38012939j],
       [ 0.5017482 -0.39747648j],
       [-1.00186317+1.02918796j]])
```

You can replace `np.random.randn(n, 2)` with `np.random.normal(size=(n, 2))` if you prefer to use that function.

According to the wikipedia article on the [complex normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution), the variance of the real and imaginary parts of a complex *standard* normal random variable should be 1/2 (so the variance of the complex samples is 1).  I'll use `np.random.normal` this time, but you could also scale `np.random.rand` appropriately.

Create a large sample so we can verify that the variance is close to 1:

```
In [19]: n = 100000                                                                                                                                                               

In [20]: z = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=np.sqrt(2)/2, size=(n, 2)).view(np.complex128)                                                                                         

In [21]: z[:10]                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[21]: 
array([[ 0.31439115+1.39059186j],
       [ 0.18306617+1.19364778j],
       [ 0.20281354+0.31695626j],
       [ 0.27230747+1.18380383j],
       [-0.71353935-0.11587812j],
       [-0.2371236 +0.91542372j],
       [ 0.04254323+1.50538309j],
       [ 0.23024067+0.96947144j],
       [ 0.6954942 +0.20933687j],
       [-0.66853093+2.00389192j]])
```

As expected, the variance is close to 1:

```
In [22]: np.var(z)                                                                                                                                                                
Out[22]: 0.9998204444495904
```

Alternatively, you can use [`np.random.multivariate_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html), and use `0.5*np.eye(2)` for the covariance matrix:

```
In [31]: z = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(2), 0.5*np.eye(2), size=n).view(np.complex128)                                                                                

In [32]: z[:10]                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[32]: 
array([[-0.25012362+0.80450233j],
       [-0.85853563+0.05350865j],
       [ 0.36715694-0.10483562j],
       [ 1.0740756 +0.081779j  ],
       [-1.04655701+0.15211247j],
       [ 0.18248473+0.49350875j],
       [ 0.6152102 +0.08037717j],
       [ 0.12423999+0.56175553j],
       [-1.05282963-0.60113989j],
       [-0.01340098+0.80751573j]])

In [33]: np.var(z)                                                                                                                                                                
Out[33]: 1.0001327524747319
```

Comment: So this is only for  `circularly-symmetric complex normal`. Any more generic way?